# how to read and remove too many unused js code in chunk

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js, google-chrome-devtools, chunks

[image]

My nextjs project calls the main page, and 98% of unused bytes exist in one chunk of chunks.

When I looked into the code, there was a red line marked on this type of code.

```
"use strict";
eval(...)
```

I'm not sure what that means. Does it mean that the unused code was imported and used?

I need your help and a keyword to find a clue.

Comment: It means "it looks like you're running webpack in dev mode". But also, did you search the web to find possible related things in authoritative places? Because I searched for that eval line, and found https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4899

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're running your tests in a development environment. that's why you're shipping so much unused JS. to fix this run `next build` to generate an optimized bundle.

in production, if you want to figure out why a package was imported I suggest using [bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@next/bundle-analyzer).

as for what they are.

- The `eval()` function evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)
- "use strict"; Defines that JavaScript code should be executed in "strict mode". [source](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp)